# Can't get Memcached to use more than 300 MB for cache

Tags: debian, memcached

I installed Memcached on a Debian 7 server with 32 GB of ram. In my /etc/memcached.conf file I
have it set up to use up to 4 GB of ram:

-m 4000

Yet, whenever I run 'top' I always see memcached using around 309m (VIRT) and 180m (SHARE). On my prior server I had 64 GB ram and set memcached to use 10GB and it always filled it up or came close. Any suggestions on what is causing memcached to always stay around 300 megabytes for its cache? I also have plenty of free memory (19263 used and 12954 free).

Comment: Are you sure the configuration isn't taking effect? Check `echo "stats settings" | nc localhost 11211|grep maxbytes`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to config within the `/etc/memcached.conf` file, the syntax is:

CACHESIZE="4096"

Comment: I believe that syntax applies to Fedora/Red Hat and not Debian.

Answer (score 0):

Check ulimits for memcache user, or maybe you just have no more data to cache than 300MB.